# Query on typecasting in solidity

Tags: solidity, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

I am following uniswap v3 development book. We have a code:

```
pool = address(
    new UniswapV3Pool{
        salt: keccak256(abi.encodePacked(tokenX, tokenY, tickSpacing))
    }()
);
```

My question is, is it necessary to typecast it to **address**??  when we are doing `new UniswapV3Pool` was not it enough to transform it in address? as UniswapV3Pool is a contract and here we are making a new instance of contract. And also solidity doc saying this:
 `D d = new D{salt: salt}(arg);` from [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#salted-contract-creations-create2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case it is necessary because if you create a new `instance` of a contract using the new keyword in Solidity, the type of the created `instance` is the contract type itself, not an `address` that would be a problem.

here is an example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    // ...
}

contract AnotherContract {
    address public myContractInstance;

    function createMyContract() public {
        // This would result in a type error because the type of 'new MyContract()' is 'MyContract', not 'address'
    
        // This would work because you are explicitly typecasting 'MyContract' to 'address'
        myContractInstance = address(new MyContract());
    }
}
```

typecasting `new UniswapV3Pool{...}()` to `address` is necessary to store the created instance in the `pool` variable, which is of type `address`

Comment: actually the function returning `returns(address pool)`, i think as pool is type of address then we had to type cast it to address

Comment: Yes, the type of the created instance is the contract type itself, not an address.